# Как разместить 1 ImageVIew в другой?

Tags: java, android

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/course_video_intro_img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/course_intro_image"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        tools:src="@drawable/profile_image2"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/play_video_btn"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_play"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Красный эти перавая картинка. А желтая это вторая, и она должна быть по центру первой.

Я конечно пробовал через android:layout_alignLeft right top bottom. Да она становиться по центру, но желтая картинка, растягивается, а мне не надо чтобы она растягивалась.

ConstainLayout не использую. С ней быстро кодить можно, но если подправить это просто ужас. Возни с ней больше и глюки какие то не понятные.

Конечно можно использовать каждый раз LinearLayout но это тоже не вариант, слишком много тормозов появляется. Читал в документах что лучше 1 Releative layout. Чем 10 LinearLayout....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раз известна точная высота картинок, размещайте их по центру родителя по горизонтали и высчитайте марджин для второй картинки для центрирования по вертикали (`(140 - 80) / 2 = 30`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/course_video_intro_img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/course_intro_image"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        tools:src="@drawable/profile_image2"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/play_video_btn"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_play"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Если высота картинок всё же не фиксирована, то можно положить их во `FrameLayout` и поставить им с `android:layout_gravity="center"`. Но это добавит один уровень вложенности.

Идеальный вариант, конечно, разобраться с `ConstraintLayout`. Он не такой страшный, как кажется.

Comment: Но в `ConstraintLayout` есть одна проблема. Если я добавлю какой нибудь LinearLayout и укажу ему clickable false. То этот параметр работать не будет. А когда родитель Releative то все работает

Comment: Если вы так хвалите ConstraintLayout. То скажите почему же ImageView с id `course_video_intro_img` поверх LineraLayout?  Я же говорю она глючная

http://ideone.com/rTWLr3

Comment: @EraNewGames Очевидно потому, что вы не разобрались, как им пользоваться. Задайте новый вопрос, если действительно интересно.